# Is it possible to create a DataGridView which looks like this?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

[image]

This have been developed by using some third party component such as C1. As you can see there are are three kinds of rows here...

`Type 1. L0000000000000000420` - this kind of row is fetched from database. (Read Only)

`Type 2. Enter Amount` - this kind of row is for the user to input amount. (this one might also contain drop downlist in some columns) (Editable only when Checked)

`Type 3. WHITE ROW`- this is just a blank Read Only row for better look and feel.

I want to know is it possible to create similar if not exactly the same kind of DataGridView without using any third party component? 
My idea is .. to fetch the rows from database into a DataTable and then loop it ... I am thinking of adding two extra blank rows in the DataTable after each row that has been fetched.

I will also add a column which will have a value such as ,

A - (this is to indicate type 1)

B - (this is to indicate type 2)

C - (this is to indicate type 3)

A

B

C .. so on

I will then check the type of row in a loop and then set property of that row to read only/ editable , color properties accordingly.

But I am not sure if this is practically possible.  I am not not sure how am i gonna add `ComboBox` for only tpe 2 column. Because if I add a ComboBox column it will be displayed in all three rows. Is this possible? If yes, can you give me some idea how? I need to know how I can do this before I ask some more specific questions. Thank You.

Comment: **Solution:** Use WPF. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, and which doesn't support anything. You can easily create something like that in WPF in some 30 to 50 lines of XAML, whereas it will take years of horrible hacks in winforms.

Comment: I am afraid I do not have enough time for learning WPF.

Comment: Are you sure you could create that look in WinForms faster than you could learn WPF?

Comment: I think, its possible but it will have to be "not binded data" but manually written and read data. It will take some custom coding. WPF is not easy to learn. I mean, you'll need some experience to use XAML to your advantage

Comment: @HighCore: WPF is not the answer to every question regarding GUIs. Just answer the question instead of hyping WPF.

Comment: @HighCore There are other discussions about WPF vs Winforms, these remarks don't add anything to the question and they don't change the fact that the OP _wants_ a Winforms solution. He doesn't have time to learn WPF, I think he's been clear enough.

Comment: @Blam Well it took me one and a half day to develop a GridView like that. I somehow doubt that I could have developed this faster by learning WPF from scratch. :)
Here's what I have developed using simple DataGridView in winform:
http://snag.gy/cpoIS.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I may agree that WPF is better/faster for these kind of things, but it's his choice whether to use it or not. And learning WPF from scratch is NOT **that** fast...

As long as manually bind your data to your `DataGridView` you can control the behavior and look of your single cells, including of course the color (that's the easiest part). I include an example for the "**disappearing combobox**" cell. The last column is a simple `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "L00000422", "", "","A" });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "Enter Amount", "", "","" });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "", "", "","" });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "L00000423", "", "" ,"B"});
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "Enter Amount", "", "", "" });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new[] { "", "", "", "" });

    foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        var r = (DataGridViewRow) row;
        foreach (var col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            var cl = (DataGridViewColumn) col;
            if (cl.Index == 3)
            {
                var cc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1[3,r.Index];
                if (r.Index % 3 != 0)
                {
                    cc.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
                    cc.ReadOnly = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cc.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.DropDownButton;
                    cc.ReadOnly = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: bravo for pointing out that a switch to WPF might not be practical and is not necessarily the answer to every question to do with UIs. Wish I could give a bonus +1 for being a good answer, too.

Comment: Why can I not use this approach for bound DataGridView? You have labelled A,B and C for same kind of row. I was thinking if can add A to those rows which had been fetched from database, B for those rows that I will be adding in a loop Enter Amount for input. And C for blank separator row. I can set the width to minimal. so that it is not displayed but I can use A,B,C as reference for formatting. Is it possible?

Comment: @Arbaaz You can do that but if you try to add rows to a databound datagridview you'll get an exception: `Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound`. Don't bind the datagridview, query your db, get the data and then manually combine your db rows and your customized rows using a loop, like you said. It's definitely possible.

Comment: @Vland yes that is exactly what I mean.. getting data from DB into a DataSet and then adding rows to it. I am working on it .. and surprisingly it does not seem very far fetched.. I am half way through it already. :)