# 'system.formatexception formatted value of the cell has a wrong type' when converting DataGridViewCheckBoxCell to DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

Ok so I am converting a some checkbox cells to textbox in DataGridView using this code..

```
 If row.Cells("LoanNo").Value.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("-") Or row.Cells("LoanNo").Value.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("L") Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells("ColCheck").Value = Nothing

                DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells("ColCheck") = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell() '''for checkbox visibility
                DataGridView1.Rows(row.Index).Cells("ColCheck").ReadOnly = True
            Else
            End If
```

I am getting `system.formatexception formatted value of the cell has a wrong type` on runtime
I am overriding this error by using

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataError(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataError
    If (TypeOf (e.Exception) Is ConstraintException) Then
        Dim view As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
        view.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "an error"
        view.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex) _
            .ErrorText = "an error"

        e.ThrowException = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not sure if I should override errors like this... because what if, there is some other kind of error with the DataGridView, I would like to see. 
Also am not sure how much this is going to effect the performance of the DataGridView.

Comment: No, you should be overriding errors. Errors are there for something: for telling you "don't do that". You shouldn't be changing the type of the cells and, in case of doing it, (not sure about the point) with lots of care. Just making a cell = new type is not doing things with lots of care but right the contrary. Perhaps you should explain the exact reasons for doing such a thing and someone might come up with an idea allowing this situation to not be required at all.

Comment: @varocarbas Please take a look at my earlier question ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955699/is-it-possible-to-create-a-datagridview-which-looks-like-this 

As you can see in the image of the DataGridView which I am trying to  develop.. I need checkbox only in one of every three rows. And that why I am converting checkbox cell to textbox. i.e to hide it

Comment: Have you tried doing the contrary? Setting the column type to default (textbox) and changing to CheckBox the cells you want? TextBox is pretty "tolerant" with errors; not the case with checkbox/combobox.

Comment: No I have not, not yet. Btw. How can I over ride just this particular error  and not the rest ?  Meanwhile, I will try to implement the reverse.

Comment: Locate the exact error you want to override (for example its name or its error code) and perform the overriding actions only if the given exception meets these conditions. But, as said, this is not a good proceeding at all.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I tested it and should work without any problem.